# SQLQuery fails when using string interpolation, how can I read the response?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, psql, npgsql

The following code is a simplified version of the code I am trying to run, but should convey the same message.

When using EF with NpgSQL I am able to call raw SQL queries using:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.SqlQuery(FormattableString sql)

For some reason when running the following code, it runs successfully:

```
//Functional Version
string TargetString = "";
FormattableString BasicVersion = $"SELECT * FROM tenant";
IQueryable<string> QueryableBasicVersion = _context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(BasicVersion);
```

Returning a QueryableBasicVersion with the Expression.Sql as "SELECT * FROM tenant" as expected. I am then able to read the response from this as expected.

But when I run the following:

```
//Non-Functional Version
string TargetString1 = "";
string ParsedVariable = "tenant";
FormattableString AdvancedVersion = $"SELECT * FROM {ParsedVariable}";
IQueryable<string> QueryablyAdvancedVersion = _context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(AdvancedVersion);
```

This should provide the **same** SQL statement but instead it is "SELECT * FROM {0}". Which should be referencing the variable on call. Then when trying to read the data in the same way as the first I get the following error:

> MessageText: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "@p0"

(In my original code, I am returning a string rather than *, and I am replacing a uuid, hence the error message above. But the same problem applies)

Why does the resulting response from the database return an error?

Does the 2nd method require a different way of reading the response?

Should it not be exactly the same call?

Comment: What happens if you just declare `AdvancedVersion` as a `string` not a `FormattableString` in the second example?

Comment: You can't give a table name as a variable, as in `select * from @p0` just doesn't work in any DBMS that I know of, when `@p0` is just a text variable, you would need to *safely* inject it instead.

Comment: This is the expected behavior according to the docs. If you don't want automatic query parameterization, use `SqlQueryRaw` method instead.

Comment: Do you use ODBC? Replace the @ with :

Comment: @Max That won't help, you can't parameterize a table name at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databases almost never support parameterizing table/column names; so `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = {SomeValue}` works, but `SELECT * FROM {SomeTable}` does not. Parameterizing table/column names as you're doing effectively creates fully dynamic SQL queries.

If you need to parameterize table/column names, you'll have to interpolate them into your SQL as a .NET string, so that the database just receives a non-parameterized string. Note that this exposes your application to SQL injection attacks, so be sure to sanitize whatever it is that your interpolating into the string.

Please see [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#dynamic-sql-and-parameters) which fully explain these concepts and the relevant APIs.

Answer (score 1):

As per response from Ivan Stoev, SqlQueryRaw worked, then you can import a string rather than a formatted string.